# Error in SSIS Package - unable to allocate an environment handle

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I have a SSIS package running daily that processes CSV files from a given directory. Each CSV file contains ~2000 rows, each row has only one column which contains a string of 10 or 11 characters. The package inserts the data into a recordset, loops over the rows and calls up to two stored procedures for each row.

Normally, only one CSV file will be in the relavant directory each day, so about 2000 rows will be processed. I added in 10 more, making for somewhere between 20,000 and 25,000 rows in total. When the package ran, it threw the following error during the last ~2000 rows:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: ERROR - unable to allocate an environment handle.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandle..ctor(SQL_HANDLE handleType, OdbcHandle parentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.CreateStatementHandle()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.GetStatementHandle()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ST_5d19344133644426ade9d7b3f8a994c2.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Some quick googling suggests this error relates to an issue with available memory, but I can't really make much sense of it.

So, I have some questions:

1) What does this error really mean in the context of trying to call a stored procedure?

2) I left the package's data flow buffer DefaultBufferSize setting as the default (10 MB, if I recall), but I was given to understand that SSIS alters the size and max rows as necessary anyway? Would this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error means, but do you have any indication that there might be memory pressure?  Is the odbc driver 32 or 64 bit?

As for how memory is managed in an SSIS dataflow, SSIS will use DefaultBufferMaxSize and DefaultBufferMaxRows as boundaries for how many rows will allocated for each buffer.  Using the defaults, it will either be up to 10 MB or 10,000 rows, whichever is more without exceeding these boundaries.  SSIS does not change these values, but you can increase the memory size up to 100 MB.

EDIT:
The formula will work something like this:

```
RowsPerBuffer = If (DefaultBufferMaxRows * RowSize) > DefaultBufferMaxSize
                    Then (DefaultBufferMaxSize / RowSize)
                    Else DefaultBufferMaxRows
```

Given your statements above, you should be seeing close to 10k rows per buffer.
Increasing the defaults would allocate more memory to the dataflow, so this could create pressure on your ODBC connection if your server is severely under-allocated with memory.

Calling one or two procs per row is an intensive process.  You might consider importing these values into a staging table and using the database engine to do the heavy lifting in a set-based fashion.

EDIT:
To clarify on the set-based approach, I come from a SQL ETL dev background, so I usually think in terms of how can I process a lot of data fast.  As well, I think of how I could do this with the least amount of development while still fulfilling the complete requirements.  So the basic rules of thumb are:

- Use SSIS out-of-the-box components where possible
- Make packages small, testable units
- Avoid row-by-row operations when possible
- Stage data in order to leverage using the database server for tasks that it is better at, like merging datasets and sorting data

So if you are calling a proc for each row, it means that there is data in SQL which is important to this rowset.  You could do the following:

- Add a foreach loop to process each file, and add your dataflow to this loop
- Replace the custom script source with a standard flat file source component
- Stage the data as-is into a SQL table
- Replace the proc logic with a SQL query which joins the datasets together to get the final resultset that you need.  This new task could go into it's own stored proc.
- call the above query in a t-SQL task in SSIS after the foreach loop completes

The end result is that you will have a better performing and more maintainable package.

Comment: It's a 64 bit driver. So, will SSIS exceed the max row setting if it hasn't hit the size limit? Could you elaborate on your last suggestion?

Comment: No, SSIS will not exceed either of these limits.  I'll update my response to make that more clear as well as what I mean as an alternative.

Comment: I think I should mention that the stored procedure that is always called, takes the string from the row as a parameter, and returns another string (and then this string is passed to the second proc call if anything was returned). I think I see what you're getting at, rather than getting the data per row I would get all the data I need in a single call. The database I'm getting the data from is also not in SQL Server, it's on a remote server. Can I do a join against a remote table?

Comment: @ScottOliver that begins to get a bit uglier depending on how much data you are retreiving, how often it changes and how complicated the logic is in the proc.  But there are a few options - Stage the remote data locally and use the process I already outlined, use a MERGE JOIN in SSIS and conditional splits to put the data together, or use a Linked Server.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like there are a lot of constraints I'll need to work through. Thanks for the suggestion, I may end up doing this in the future.